# Execute SSIS Task More Than Once

Tags: ssis

I am relatively new to SSIS. I have two script tasks. If either task fails, the error handling logic is the same. The second script task must always execute regardless if the first script task has failed.

I have created the above as shown in the image link below. However, It seems the error handler task is only executed once. So if both script tasks terminate in error, the error handler is not executed for the second script task (presumably because it was already executed after the first script task.

Is there anyway to achieve this or do I simply have to duplicate the Error Handler task for both script tasks.

see SSIS Image below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to duplicate the task to have it execute twice.

One way to have this event fire twice while only defining it once is to set up an event handler.

To do this,  navigate to the 'Event Handlers' tab.

You'll see there is a dropdown on the right, where you can select the event handler type. Here you'd probably want either `OnTaskFailed` or `OnError`. `OnTaskFailed` fires once per failed task, whereas `OnError` fires for every error that occurs within a task.

On the left, you can select the executable, which allows you to define a scope for the event handler. If you scope this to the package, you'll have event handlers executed for every task in the package. If there are more tasks in your package than the two Script Tasks you've shown in your post, and you only want it fired for those two, you could put them into a Sequence Container (in the Control Flow), and then scope the event handler to that Sequence Container.

You then just click the text in the middle of the pane to create a handler, and add the necessary tasks there (it works in a similar way to the Control Flow).

The event handler will now execute for both tasks.

It's also worth mentioning that within these handlers are lots of useful system variables you can use, e.g., `System::ErrorDescription` in `OnError`.

What I've described will look something like this:

[image: SSIS Event Handling]